# How to resolve codehaus "service unavailable" maven build error?

Tags: spring, maven, broadleaf-commerce

As codehaus repository is no longer available, I get the following error whenever I try to do "Run As - Maven install" in Eclipse. Below is the error that I get:

> [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata
>   org.eclipse.core:commands/maven-metadata.xml from/to Codehaus Internal
>   (http://repository.codehaus.org): Failed to transfer
>   http://repository.codehaus.org/org/eclipse/core/commands/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Error code 503, Service Temporarily Unavailable Downloading:
>   http://repository.codehaus.org/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml

I also see that maven dependency problem has started coming up for one of the jar files that is not there in `Demosite -> pom.xml`. Below is the complete error information:

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1: ArtifactResolutionException:
>   Failure to transfer org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.1.1 from
>   http://repository.codehaus.org was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   Codehaus Internal has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.1.1
>   from/to Codehaus Internal (http://repository.codehaus.org): Failed to
>   transfer
>   http://repository.codehaus.org/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom.
>   Error code 503, Service Temporarily Unavailable

How to resolve these 2 blockers?

Answer (score 10):

Since Codehaus.org artifacts have all been transfered to Central, one easy way to keep using legacy pom.xml files is to declare the mirror as such in your settings.xml, e.g. :

```
<mirror>
  <id>RIP Codehaus</id>
  <mirrorOf>codehaus.org</mirrorOf>
  <name>Codehaus.org repo is now in Central. R.I.P.</name>
  <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
</mirror>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Codehaus services 503 message:

> All Codehaus services will be terminated progressively until May 17th 2015
>
> If you have been directed here, then the service you are accessing may have been disabled already, or we are trying to get your attention by blacking out services early.

See more detailed information here: https://www.codehaus.org/

If you have these repositories configured in any `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` you need to change these to another or just remove these, if these dependencies are in the default repository.

For example, for `restlet` you may use this repository: http://maven.restlet.com/

If this repository is in a `pom.xml` from a dependecy, just let pass this message, the download will be tried in another repository.

Answer (score 0):

We have removed this repository from the Broadleaf pom.xml, thanks for pointing it out. This was originally added because MVEL did not have a Java 8-compatible jar uploaded to Maven Central.

See https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/issues/1367 for reference.

Comment: gr8. Is there any need to do any changes in demosite also?

Answer (score 0):

the codehaus repository is mirrored Mulesoft  in the following repo:

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/